# Calculate the sum of reciprocal of setbits of a number in range

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit, counting

How to calculate the sum of reciprocal of set bits of a range of numbers [A,B]
(Here  A,B>0&&A,B<10^9) ?

My Approach:

By using a simple for loop from A to B, I have counted the setbits of a number using _builtin_popcount (an inbuilt function for counting setbits of a number in C/C++) and then took its reciprocal and added. This is an O(n) approach.But it takes longer time due to larger constraints.How can I optimise further?Can a O(log(n)) algorithm be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `F(N, k) = |{m | m is an integer lying in [0, N] and m's binary representation has exactly k bits set}|`. The answer you want is `SUM{ (F(B,k) - F(A-1,k))/k | 1<=k<=MSB(B)}`, where `MSB` = most significant bit.

You can compute `F(N,k)` recursively. Handle the boundaries of your recursion correctly. The actual recursion is

```
F(N, k) = F(N^(1<<MSB(N)), k-1) + F((1<<MSB(N))-1, k)
```

In words, you consider those numbers which have the same `MSB` as `N` and those which have `MSB` less than that of `N` and recurse.

The runtime is `O(log(B)*log(B))`.

EDIT : Illustrating the recursion :

`N = 1101`, in binary, `k=2`.
The set of numbers `<= N`, with `MSB` being the same as `N` are `{1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101}`. Notice that they are in fact the same as this set `1000 + {000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101}`. In other words, they are all the numbers `<= N^(1<<MSB(N)) = 1101 ^ 1000 = 101`. Since you already count the `MSB` bit, the number of bits you need from the set `{000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101}` is `k-1`. That explains the `F(N^(1<<MSB(N)), k-1)` term.

The set of numbers `<=N`, with `MSB` being less than `N` are `{000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111}`. In other words, all the numbers `<= (1<<MSB(N)) - 1 = 1000 - 1 = 111`. So far, you haven't counted any set bits. So, you still need `k` bits from the numbers in the set `{000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111}`. That is where the `F((1<<MSB(N))-1, k)` term comes from.

Comment: Is there any base condition for the function?

Comment: `k=0`is the trivially handled base condition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.It would be better if you can post the psuedo code for the function as I still could not understand the boundaries of the recursion.

Comment: @typedef I had a typo in the recursion - it should be 'xor' instead of 'and'. I have also added a more detailed explanation of the recursion. Hope that helps.